# How to parse fetched data into different cells rather than only one cell in my case

Tags: json, firebase, google-apps-script, google-sheets

How to parse fetched data into different cells rather than only one cell as in my case in the following code:

```
function getFrenchContacts() {
  var firebaseUrl = "https://project_dump.firebaseio.com/";
  var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl);
  var proj = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Enter project ID').getRange('B1').getValue();
  var queryParameters = {orderBy:"project_id", equalTo: proj};
  var data = base.getData("", queryParameters)
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Fetch');


sheet.getRange('A1').setValue(JSON.stringify(data).substring(0, 50000));

  }
```

Comment: What is the data you're trying to parse? What format is it in?

Comment: It is in the following format    {"207272":{"Key":207272,"city_display_name":"Hyderabad","customer_name":"Pavan -","display_name":"Additional Charges","order_date":"2020-02-27T00:00:00.000Z","order_id":2002270214,"product_name":"2BHK Deep Cleaning","project_id":480044,"quantity":1,"sku_code":"LSLSLS0005S0001","super_category":"PO Services","total_value":5500,"unit":"Fixed"}

Comment: It is in json format

Comment: How are you wanting this in the sheet? As is, you're setting a string to a single cell so this is expected behaviour.

Comment: I don't know how to parse this into different cells that is why I'm adding it in just one cell

Comment: But what do you mean `into different cells`? In what format? It's a JSON there is no expected way for this to go into the Sheet. As rows? As Columns? As a visual representation of the object?

Comment: Yes as rows. Thanks

Comment: Check out the [`.setValues()` method of the `Range` class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) and format your data to meet the expected input type. To set values to more than one cell you need to specify the range, and the values in a 2D array format (`[][]`). From the incomplete JSON you provided it is not clear to see what kind of data you could be getting and wanting to put into a Sheet. I suggest you have a look through the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ask a new question if you can't get this to work.